# More efficient way of counting proportion of random numbers below threshold

Tags: r

Working on some probability exercises, I need to plot the proportion of the times a coin comes up heads (unfair coin with p=0.3 for example) - versus the number of flips of the coin.

Here is my python inspired R code (it compiles and runs) that runs very slowly. Is there any way to make it more idiomatic R code?

Much appreciated

```
flip_experiment <- function(prob_heads, n_flips) {
  proportion_heads <- c()
  for (i in 1:n_flips) {
    count = 0
    for (j in 1:i){
      if(runif(1, 0, 1) <= prob_heads){
        # We flipped a head!
        count <- count + 1
      }
    }
    prop_heads = count / i
    proportion_heads <- append(proportion_heads, prop_heads)

  }
  plot(1:n_flips, proportion_heads)
  return 
}

flip_experiment(0.3, 1000);
flip_experiment(0.03, 1000);
```

Here is one of the graphs:

[image]

Comment: in this case of simulations, it's always good idea to `set.seed` first, so you can get consistent results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least the `j`-loop can be vectorized (using `runif(i, 0, 1)` rather than calling `runif(1, 0, 1)` for `i` times). Also, don't grow the resulting `proportion_heads` vector. Its size is known so you can pre-allocate it and fill in.

```
flip_experiment <- function(prob_heads, n_flips) {
  proportion_heads <- numeric(n_flips)
  for (i in 1:n_flips) {
    count <- sum(runif(i, 0, 1) <= prob_heads)
    proportion_heads[i] <- count / i  
    }
  plot(1:n_flips, proportion_heads)
  }

flip_experiment(0.3, 1000);
flip_experiment(0.03, 1000);
```

A second thought:

```
flip_experiment <- function(prob_heads, n_flips) {
  proportion_heads <- cumsum(runif(n_flips, 0, 1) <= prob_heads) / seq_len(n_flips)
  plot(1:n_flips, proportion_heads)
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function I proposed using the `rbinom` function.

```
flip_experiment2 <- function(prob_heads, n_flips){
  proportion_heads <- rbinom(n_flips, 1:n_flips, prob_heads)/(1:n_flips)
  return(plot(x = 1:n_flips, y = proportion_heads))
}
```

Here I conducted a benchmark analysis. Using `rbinom` is a lot faster.

```
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(m1 = flip_experiment(0.3, 1000), 
               m2 = flip_experiment2(0.3, 1000))

Unit: milliseconds
 expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
   m1 765.22263 859.28831 923.04026 900.44548 970.77151 1259.4624   100   b
   m2  27.88089  29.93146  33.50223  31.55485  33.50544  146.7657   100  a
```

Comment: I didn't get to distributions in the book yet :-)

Answer (score 1):

R is beautiful because you don't need for loops in most cases:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- 1:1000
y <- sapply(x, function(j) sum(rbinom(j, size = 1, prob = .3))/j)
plot(x, y)
```

**Explanation**

The toss of a coin follows a binomial distribution. In R you can obtain random results for a number of distributions (see `?distribution`), one of which is the binomial one with `rbinom` (r here goes for random). The `sapply` bit goes for simplified apply, a vectorization. The `sum` and dividing, you follow for sure ;)

Comment: I didn't get to distributions in the book yet :-)

Answer (score 0):

a `tidyverse` based solution is also very efficient:

```
library(tidyverse)
flip.experiment <- function(prob.heads, n.flips){
  dat = tibble(exp.no = 1:n.flips, flip.no = 1:n.flips)
  dat = dat %>% 
    group_by(exp.no) %>% 
    expand(flip.no = 1:exp.no) %>%
    mutate(head = if_else(runif(exp.no, 0, 1) <= prob.heads, TRUE, FALSE)) %>%
    summarise(proportion.heads = sum(head)/n())
  plot <- plot(dat$exp.no, dat$proportion.heads)
  return(plot)
}
flip.experiment(0.3, 1000)
```